# Как вывести в thymeleaf вложенный набор?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Есть класс Person, который содержит поле тип Set addresses. Каким образом вывести информацию по Addresses?

Информацию по Person вывожу следующим образом:

```
<div>
    <p th:each="person : ${persons}"
       th:text="${person.id} + '. ' + ${person.lastName} + ' ' + ${person.firstName} +
        ' ' + ${person.patronymic} + '. Тел.: ' + ${person.addresses}"></p>
</div>
```

---

Класс Address:

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String addressLine1;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String addressLine2;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String city;

    @NotNull
    @Size
    private String region;

    @NotNull
    @Size
    private String country;

    @NotNull
    @Size
    private String zipCode;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Address(@NotNull @Size(max = 100) String addressLine1, @NotNull @Size(max = 100) String addressLine2,
                   @NotNull @Size(max = 100) String city, @NotNull @Size String region,
                   @NotNull @Size String country, @NotNull @Size String zipCode) {
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
        this.city = city;
        this.region = region;
        this.country = country;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Сработала вот такая конструкция:

```
<section th:each="person : ${persons}">
    <p th:text="${person.getLastName()}"></p>
    <ul>
        <li th:each="phone: ${person.getPhoneNumbers()}" th:text="${phone.getNumber()}"></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```